# Vulkan is unable to detect Nvidia GPU from within a docker container when using the Nvidia Container Toolkit

Tags: docker, ubuntu, nvidia, vulkan, nvidia-docker

My goal is to be able to run Vulkan application in a docker container using the [Nvidia Container Toolkit](https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/cloud-native/container-toolkit/overview.html). Ideally running Ubuntu 22.04 on the host and in the container.

I've created a git repo to allow others to better reproduce this issue: https://github.com/rickyjames35/vulkan_docker_test
The [README](https://github.com/rickyjames35/vulkan_docker_test/blob/fcf930ab143f596fcecb59f2b1c8e397c4799d38/README.md) explains my findings but I will reiterate them here.

For this test I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 on my host as well as in the container `FROM ubuntu:22.04`. For this test I'm seeing that the only device `vulkaninfo` is finding is `llvmpipe` which is a CPU based graphics driver. I'm also seeing that llvmpipe can't render when running `vkcube` both in the container and on the host for Ubuntu 22.04. Here is the container output for `vkcube`:

```
Selected GPU 0: llvmpipe (LLVM 13.0.1, 256 bits), type: 4
Could not find both graphics and present queues
```

On my host I can tell it to use `llvmpipe`:

```
vkcube --gpu_number 1
Selected GPU 1: llvmpipe (LLVM 13.0.1, 256 bits), type: Cpu
Could not find both graphics and present queues
```

As you can see they have the same error. What's interesting is if I swap the container to `FROM ubuntu:20.04` then `llvmpipe` can render but this is moot since I do not wish to do CPU rendering. The main issue here is that Vulkan is unable to detect my Nvidia GPU from within the container when using the [Nvidia Container Toolkit](https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/cloud-native/container-toolkit/overview.html) with `NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES=all` and `NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=all`. I've also tried using [nvidia/vulkan](https://gitlab.com/nvidia/container-images/vulkan). When running `vulkaninfo` in this container I get:

```
vulkaninfo
ERROR: [Loader Message] Code 0 : vkCreateInstance: Found no drivers!
Cannot create Vulkan instance.
This problem is often caused by a faulty installation of the Vulkan driver or attempting to use a GPU that does not support Vulkan.
ERROR at /vulkan-sdk/1.3.236.0/source/Vulkan-Tools/vulkaninfo/vulkaninfo.h:674:vkCreateInstance failed with ERROR_INCOMPATIBLE_DRIVER
```

I'm suspecting this has to to with me running Ubuntu 22.04 on the host although the whole point of docker is the host OS generally should not affect the container.

In the test above I was using `nvidia-driver-525` I've tried using different versions of the driver with the same results. At this point I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if Vulkan is not supported in the Nvidia Container Toolkit for Ubuntu 22.04 even though it claims to be.

Comment: This post looks like it could be relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74025631/vulkan-does-not-detect-gpu-when-running-unity-build-in-docker-container?rq=1

Comment: I can reproduce this issue with nvidia/vulkan images. i.e.

This works

`docker run --rm -it --gpus all nvidia/vulkan:1.2.133-450 vulkaninfo`

This doesn't

`docker run --rm -it --gpus all nvidia/vulkan:1.3-470 vulkaninfo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working all the way without needing to copy over `nvidia_icd.json`. Ian Purton your answer was very helpful in tracking down the answer. It led me here https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-container-toolkit/issues/16 which shows that what Ian Purton posted was required until v1.12.0 of the NVIDIA Container Toolkit which fixes this problem. I've updated my repo with the fix. https://github.com/rickyjames35/vulkan_docker_test What I have in my repo is the most bare bones way you can run Vulkan in a docker container using `docker compose`.

Answer (score 3):

The vulkan drivers on 22.04 were at version 1.1 if you use ubuntu:23_04 you get vulkan 1.3 drivers and I was able to get this to work with the following

```
FROM ubuntu:23.04

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

ENV NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES compute,graphics,utility

# Install Vulkan
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
    libxext6 \
    libvulkan1 \
    libvulkan-dev \
    vulkan-tools


COPY nvidia_icd.json /etc/vulkan/icd.d
```

You'll also need this nvidia_icd.json

```json
{
    "file_format_version" : "1.0.0",
    "ICD": {
        "library_path": "libGLX_nvidia.so.0",
        "api_version" : "1.3"
    }
}
```

Then inside you new container you can run `vulkaninfo --summary` and see your nvidia card.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when trying to set up a docker container using the nvidia/cuda:12.0.0-devel-ubuntu22.04 image.

I was able to get it to work using the unityci/editor image. This is the docker command I used.

```
docker run -dit -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix/:/tmp/.X11-unix/ -v /dev:/dev --gpus='all,"capabilities=compute,utility,graphics,display"' unityci/editor:ubuntu-2022.2.1f1-base-1.0.1
```

After setting up the container, I had to apt install `vulkan-utils` and `libnvidia-gl-525` then everything works.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Was having the same problem with `vulkaninfo` only reporting the llvmpipe device inside the container, even though `nvidia-smi` output was identical to the host system, where `vulkaninfo` correctly reported the GPU.

None of the above solutions worked for me. But upgrading nvidia-container-toolkit to 1.14.4 following instructions here https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/cloud-native/container-toolkit/1.14.4/install-guide.html resolved the issue.