# Out of memoryvulkan error on unreal engine docker container works fine on host nvidia cuda setup followed

Tags: docker, ubuntu, nvidia, unreal-engine5

I get the following error when I run a docker container for my unreal engine build.

```
username@remotemachine:~/some_dir$ sudo docker compose up --build --remove-orphans
[+] Building 10.9s (10/10) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                 docker:default
 => [unreal_engines internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.43kB                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [unreal_engines internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => [unreal_engines internal] load metadata for ghcr.io/epicgames/unreal-engine:runtime-pixel-streaming                                                                                       0.5s
 => [unreal_engines internal] load build context                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => => transferring context: 16.54kB                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => CACHED [unreal_engines 1/5] FROM ghcr.io/epicgames/unreal-engine:runtime-pixel-streaming@sha256:850053682a73e05e59ae9712486fa7e38d26e27c44c7daaf204423e1aa8eac39                          0.0s
 => [unreal_engines 2/5] COPY --chown=ue4:ue4 . /data                                                                                                                                         2.6s
 => [unreal_engines 3/5] WORKDIR /data                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [unreal_engines 4/5] RUN chown -R ue4:ue4 /data                                                                                                                                           3.8s
 => [unreal_engines 5/5] RUN chmod 755 /data                                                                                                                                                  0.4s
 => [unreal_engines] exporting to image                                                                                                                                                       3.6s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                       3.5s
 => => writing image sha256:fa8ab32810c14a21288bf5108e444441f2b974aeaf8b1495ad7e6667f31b6fdb                                                                                                  0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/some_docker_project-unreal_engines                                                                                                                0.0s
[+] Running 1/0
 ✔ Container engine_1  Recreated                                                                                                                                                              0.1s
Attaching to engine_1
engine_1  | 5.1.1-23901901+++UE5+Release-5.1 1008 0
engine_1  | Disabling core dumps.
engine_1  | Resizing viewport due to setres change, 1024 x 768
engine_1  | Failed to find symbol file, expected location:
engine_1  | "/data/CesiumTerrain/Binaries/Linux/ProjectName-Linux-Shipping.sym"
engine_1  | LowLevelFatalError [File:.\Runtime/VulkanRHI/Private/VulkanMemory.cpp] [Line: 2025]
engine_1  | Out of memory on Vulkan; MemoryTypeIndex=1, AllocSize=128.000MB
engine_1  | Signal 11 caught.
engine_1  | Malloc Size=262146 LargeMemoryPoolOffset=262162
[+] Stopping 1/1onUnixCrashHandler: Signal=11
 ✔ Container engine_1  Stopped                                                                                                                                                               10.5s
canceled  | Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The Dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM ghcr.io/epicgames/unreal-engine:runtime-pixel-streaming

COPY --chown=ue4:ue4 . /data

WORKDIR /data

RUN chown -R ue4:ue4 /data
RUN chmod 755 /data

# Enable the NVIDIA driver capabilities required by the NVENC API
ENV NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES=all
ENV GPUS=all
#ENV NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=nvidia.com/gpu=all
ENV __NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1
ENV __VK_LAYER_NV_optimus=NVIDIA_only
ENV DISPLAY=0.0



#new entrypoint way
ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/bash", "./ProjectName.sh", "-PixelStreamingIP=ip_here", "-PixelStreamingPort=port_here", "-RenderOffscreen" ]
```

and the docker-compose.yml is this:

```
services:
    unreal_engines:
        container_name: engine_1
        runtime: nvidia
        privileged: true
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        restart: always
        network_mode: host
        volumes:
            - /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix
        entrypoint:
            - /data/ProjectName.sh
            - -RenderOffScreen
            - -Unattended
            - -PixelStreamingIP=ip_here
            - -PixelStreamingPort=port_here
```

Running it unprivileged just gets a fail on error one - seems like there is some kind of error in linking the container to the GPU - when I test out the sample cuda container from the nvidia documenation I get the following:

```
myuser@remotemachine:~/somedirectory$ sudo docker run --rm --runtime=nvidia --gpus all ubuntu nvidia-smi
Wed Sep 27 15:00:28 2023
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 535.54.03              Driver Version: 535.54.03    CUDA Version: 12.2     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA A10                     Off | 00000000:00:04.0 Off |                    0 |
|  0%   77C    P0             149W / 150W |  21498MiB / 23028MiB |     99%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Are there some kinds of installations I am missing for the image? or some kind of environmental variables I need to set?

I have cobbled together this setup from various other issues and how tos so happy to hear if I need a complete reset.

Here is a list of used links with similar issues that don't seem to fix it:

- https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/large-memory-pool-error-on-a-computer-with-60gb-of-ram/409112
- https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/failed-to-find-symbol-file-expected-location/446269
- https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/why-unreal-crashes-at-launch/540031/3
- https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/ue5-on-linux-built-game-errors/247496/2
- https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/ue5-crashing-on-startup/531424/5
- https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=372592
- https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/i-keep-getting-errors-related-to-vulkanrhi-so/719723
- https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/ue5-fails-to-startup-on-linux/582815/4
- https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=285971
- [Vulkan is unable to detect Nvidia GPU from within a docker container when using the Nvidia Container Toolkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74965945/vulkan-is-unable-to-detect-nvidia-gpu-from-within-a-docker-container-when-using)
- https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-container-toolkit/issues/16
- https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/having-problem-running-pixel-streaming-in-docker-failed-to-create-a-cuda-context/603210
- https://github.com/adamrehn/ue4-runtime
- http://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/435.17/README/primerenderoffload.html
- reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/ctzud9/nvidia_prime_render_offload_on_a_desktop_with/
- https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/out-of-memory-bug-running-4-22-x-on-linux-with-vulkan/449034
- https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/vulkan-rhi-causing-regular-engine-crash-assertion-failed-error/479354/6
- https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/creating-project-using-ue4-editor-fails-on-docker-container/1198211/2
- https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/cannot-execute-ue4-run-in-container/1211260/2
- https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/having-problem-running-pixel-streaming-in-docker-failed-to-create-a-cuda-context/603210/3
- https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/ue5-2-1-crash-when-opening-projects-with-nvidia-optimus-card-latest-drivers/1258549
- https://github.com/lukehb/PixelStreamingDemoMinimal/blob/master/Dockerfile
- https://github.com/ImmortalEmperor/UnrealEngine/blob/4.25-pixelstreaming/pixel-streaming-cloud.md